# JLPT N3 Grammar - Passive form AND passive + te iru

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I picked up the 日本語総まとめ book and I don't quite understand their explanation of passive.

The book says that passive can be used when you mention a fact without a subject. However, in the example (below), to me the subject is the entrance ceremony.

> 入学式は、このホールで行われます。
>
> 昔は、その考えが正しいと思われていた。

Can anyone offer a clearer explanation of this and also the usage of the te-iru conjugation with passive?

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits StackExchange Q&A format. You supposedly take two very brief sentences from a book and ask for "*a clearer explanation*". And the second request is even more broad and unclear: "*offer me an explanation of the usage of the te-iru conjugation*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have read in your textbook is equally true in English, too.

> - 入学式は、このホールで行われます。
>     The entrance ceremony will be held in this hall (*by us*).
> - 昔は、その考えが正しいと思われていた。
>     In the past, it was thought (*by people*) that the idea was correct.

The original (active) versions of these sentences are:

> - このホールで入学式を行います。 (omitted subject = 我々 (we))
>     *We* will hold the entrance ceremony in this hall.
> - 昔は、人々はその考えが正しいと思っていた。 (subject = 人々 (people))
>     In the past, *people* thought the idea was correct.

The book's explanation means you can omit the subject of the **original** (active) sentence once it has been turned to passive. See how "we (us)" and "people" can be omitted in the passive versions.

～(ら)れている is simply the combination of passive and ている (e.g., 今、私は見られている = "I am being seen now."; そのCDはもう発売されている = "The CD has already been released."). If you're not sure why you need ている in the second example, see the following questions.

- [思っている/言っている with third person subject?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6538/5010)
- [Difference between volitional +と思う and volitional+ と思っている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40145/5010)