# ワクワクする vs ワクワクしている

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in actual meaning/usage?

The example is from https://hanasu-eigo.com/2017/01/11/325/

> “I’m excited!” というのは、「すごく楽しみなことがあってワクワクしている」というような時に使います
>
> and then had an example below:
>
> “I’m going to Japan for the first time. I’m so excited!“
>
> 初めて日本に行くの。すっごいワクワクする！

I've read and listened to enough that I would know if someone was excited about something, but if I used the words themselves, I imagine I would end up using ワクワクしている more often than natives would (where they would simply use ワクワクする).

Comment: is that the translation given or is it your translation? because to me it looks more like someone saying, “you’re going to japan?  it’ll be incredibly exciting”

Comment: its the given translation, but it was merely an example to ask the question (i.e. ignore their translation if you like and explain the difference between using the plain form, or している)

Comment: well i now noticed the link. i’m a bit confused by this use of の. maybe that’s a colloquialism for のだ. i don’t know. but the fact that the going to japan is an event yet to happen the use of the plain form of the verb seems more natural to me. but i think someone else should answer the nuance in this case.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62826/7810